# Change Check Out Folder for checked out files in SourceSafe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I had to rebuild my machine and went from XP to Windows 7.  I've now got a bit of an issue: I had files checked out in SourceSafe previously, which I still have copies of in the local folder on my new install.  However, SourceSafe still has them checked out to the old XP folder (c:\documents and settings etc) whereas the files now reside in c:\Users.

Pending Checkins in Visual Studio now thinks I have nothing checked out, and SourceSafe declares that the files are checked out to me under the c:\documents and settings\ path.

Is there any way to tell SourceSafe to simply "look over there" for the files instead? It seems to work with individually undoing and redoing checkout on the files, but that's a lengthy process and one I'd like to avoid if possible.  If I simply checkout the files individually then it lists them as checked out to me twice, one for each of the locations.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the working folder to the new location, you can check out the file again, but check the "don't get local copy" checkbox.  Now you've got it checked out in the correct location and can check the file in.

Or, when you choose to check in a single file, you can click "Browse" to select a file from a different location.

This is with an older version of SourceSafe (VSS6), but hopefully the UI hasn't changed much since then.

Comment: In VSS6, I couldn't check them out again--just got messages that they are already checked out.  However (knowing I have a good backup), I was able to choose Undo Checkout with Local Copy: Leave.  THEN I could check them out with "Don't get local copy".

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, it's getting hard for me to remember my VSS...  (I'm doing this all from memory)

Can't you right-click on your folder in VSS and select "Check In..." and point it to your new local copy?  I've done something like this before.  It warns you that it's checked out to a different place, but it will check in the files...